# Where should I ask job-related questions?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs, site-recommendation

Where should I place this type of question?

- How can I get a good job in the USA in the Web Design/Development field if I'm currently living in another country?
- What other things are needed to live and work in the USA other than knowledge and experience?
- Should I send my resume to any company in the USA and have them call me directly to arrange all necessities? Or would they not ever hire me because I live in another country, even if I'm perfect for their requirements?

Comment: +1, "where should i..." is a good question.  -1, "why doesn't..." is a horrible title.  net vote: 0.

Comment: For point (2) you'll need a work permit and that's not that easy to get.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note (not by OP): this answer was accurate during the brief Stack Exchange 1.0 era, but all of the links are now broken.

Check out the *many* sites here, some of which will be suitable for your question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

In particular these two might be good candidates:

http://careeroverflow.com/

http://advice.personforce.com/

Good luck!

Comment: response is very slow on these two

Comment: You should have seen SO when it only had a handful of active users!

Comment: actually, it was great even at the private beta

Comment: @Downvoter - Careeroverflow is only 20 days old.  Stackoverflow was about as 'hopping' as Careeroverflow at 20 days old.  By the time I joined the SO beta a few months after the beta started, yes, it was great.  But at 20 days?  Still pretty slow.

Comment: yeah, i have started there, in careeroverflow. It's slow but it's seem have great prospect. Maybe after a few month, the site will be more crowned.

Comment: -1: advice.personforce.com is down.